# Fetching previous saved database file after reinstalling the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

I am new to ios development so please pardon if I am asking a silly question.

I need to check if my `sql` file from the previous installation of the same app exists in the device directory already. If yes, then I need to fetch that file instead of making the new one. But the bundle folder of the app changes after reinstalling the app. So I cant guess the name of the previously installed app bundle folder. I tried to save it elsewhere on the device, but it isn't allowing me. Please suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for isn't possible.  If an app is removed, all its files are deleted as well.  In iOS, there is no app-neutral place to store files.  When an app is merely updated, the update happens "in place" from the perspective of the app, and all previous files are available.

If you want files to survive a delete-reinstall cycle, you'll have to use a cloud service, such as iCloud, Dropbox or Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

once app is deleted. Application bundle and document directory and all files (including SQLite file)are deleted. u have to fetch all data from API.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS each application is a Sandbox. This Sandbox consists of Application bundle and Mutable part where you store your database and other files which are mutated during the life span of an application.

When you delete the application, entire Sandbox is removed. The only thing which does not get remove is the data which you have stored in keychain.

When you update the application, only application bundle gets updated and Mutable part remain un-touched. So while re-installing  the application when it is already present (technically updating the existing application on the device), you can find the same file from the same location.

Comment: How to get that location?

Comment: I know that my sql file is still there. I can manual go to that folder saved when app was previously installed  and check. I checked, the file does exist there even after reinstalling. But how to get that location of previously saved file after installation?

Comment: Get the path of Document directory and append path component where the file is located.

Comment: How can I get the path component of the file to append..?? that is my question.

Comment: That only you can make. In the previous version, where did you store the file? Go to same place and find the file from that place. If this is not known to you, iterate entire documents directory and get the required path of a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing you can take daily backup of that file on remote server and when you reinstall app check that file exist on server if exists than download else create new.